# How to pop up java jar file after clicking button on the website (php)?

Tags: java, php, executable-jar

I have a button and when I click the button on the website, my Java application which I save it as an executable jar file will pop up. How should I do it? Is it possible to just use a  href command or onClick command? But it doesn't seem right. Or do I need to play around with the server, as in this case I use Wamp as my server.

Hoping to get some suggestions from the team. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java already has a technology for doing this and is called java webstart.

This is what you are looking for :  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/

See an example here :-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/developing.html

Comment: in the example, it shows that after clicking the launch button, the java application will be downloaded and then I can run the application. But all I want is to just pop up the application without downloading it first. Is it possible?

Comment: no, in that way it can't be done. Java Web start is the option. Even when you embed applets onto webpages they are first downloaded onto your system and then they are interpreted by the JVM and they run on webpages.